# An indexed array of an array of objects

Tags: php

How do I create (in PHP) and array of an array of objects?  For example, say I have:

```
$arr[0] = array("eref_id" => "A001", "eref_child" => "A100", "level" => 1);
$arr[1] = array("eref_id" => "A002", "eref_child" => "A200", "level" => 2);
$arr[2] = array("eref_id" => "A003", "eref_child" => "A300", "level" => 3);
$arr[3] = array("eref_id" => "A003", "eref_child" => "A310", "level" => 3);
```

An I want a new array where the elements of "arr" are the "eref_id" and "eref_child" but the index to the array is the "level" element.  So basically,

```
$newarr[1] would contain $arr[0]
$newarr[2] would contain $arr[1]
$newarr[3] would contain $arr[2]
```

and `$arr[3]` (since both have a "level" of 3).

This would contain an array of `$arr[2]` and `$arr[3]`.

Hopefully this makes sense

Comment: Surely you've tried something. Post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr[0] = array("eref_id" => "A001", "eref_child" => "A100", "level" => 1);
$arr[1] = array("eref_id" => "A002", "eref_child" => "A200", "level" => 2);
$arr[2] = array("eref_id" => "A003", "eref_child" => "A300", "level" => 3);
$arr[3] = array("eref_id" => "A003", "eref_child" => "A310", "level" => 3);

foreach($arr as $a){
    $newarr[$a['level']][] = $a;
}

echo '<pre>',print_r($newarr),'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with [ouzo goodies](https://github.com/letsdrink/ouzo-goodies)

In php 5.4:

```
$result = Arrays::toMap($arr, Functions::extract()['level']);
```

In php 5.3:

```
$result = Arrays::toMap($arr, function($elem) { return $elem['level']; });
```

If you had an array of e.g. User objects:

```
$cities = Arrays::map($users, Functions::extract()->getAddress('home')->city);
```

Check out: http://ouzo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utils/functions.html#extract